# Need to parse a log and create 2 controlled groups where one group has text of the other group

Tags: regex, grok

I was wondering if someone can help me with a parsing problem.  I've been working on parsing a particular log where I'm using controlled groups (Description, FooBar, etc.).  Parsing this log has been a big challenge.

The log file looks like this:

```
2021-02-10T09:0022.041-05:00 | Info | TransactionGUID=yyyy1234-12a1-1a99-1234-01ab1ab12abc | TransactionID=123456 | Saving uploaded file to shared folder \\foobar\foo\fil\ENV1\ABMylocingZone\TIMS\FileTemplates\12345678_12345678_01ab1ab12abc-99f5-4a43-9127-01ab1ab12abc.xlsx | CopyToSharedFolder()
```

I need to place this set of text:

> **Saving uploaded file to shared folder \foobar\foo\fil\ENV1\ABMylocingZone\TIMS\FileTemplates\12345678_12345678_01ab1ab12abc-99f5-4a43-9127-01ab1ab12abc.xlsx | CopyToSharedFolder()**

into the "Description" capture group.

I need to place this set of text:

> **12345678**

in the "FooBar" capture group.

Below is what I was able to come up with thus far. If I try to add the FooBar control group (omitted from below rule), I lose part of the Description controlled group. Because of the application I'm working with, I need to use the [GROK Debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) to create and debug my rule:

```
[A-Za-z0-9]{0,7}%{SPACE}%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:dateTime}%{SPACE}\|%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:Loglevel}%{SPACE}\|%{SPACE}TransactionGUID=%{UUID:GUID}%{SPACE}\|%{SPACE}TransactionID=%{NUMBER:TransactionId}%{SPACE}\|%{SPACE}(?<Description>(?<=\|\s).*(?=\)?))
```

Comment: You cannot assign a group value when matching a string with regex. Regex engine only can find existing text in the given string with the pattern and populate the groups with the found texts.

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew, thank you for your feedback on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short version:**

This message...

```
MyGroup12345679ContainsInfo
```

... gets captured by the `message` group, and has the number it contains captured by the `hidden_message` group.

```
(?<message>[a-zA-Z]+(?<hidden_message>%{NUMBER})[a-zA-Z]+)
```

---

**Complete version:**

As for your exact log, I would parse it this way : (had to replace `UUID` with `NUMBER` for testing purpose)

```
grok {
    message => [
        "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:dateTime}%{SPACE}\|%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:Loglevel}%{SPACE}\|%{SPACE}TransactionGUID=%{NUMBER:GUID}%{SPACE}\|%{SPACE}TransactionID=%{NUMBER:TransactionId}%{SPACE}\|%{SPACE}(?<Description>.*(\\(?<FooBar>[0-9]+)_[^\\]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+).*)",
         "+ the pattern you are using now, unless there is always a path to match there"
    ]
}
```

Tested log:

```
2021-02-10T09:0022.041-05:00 | Info | TransactionGUID=82147 | TransactionID=123456 | Saving uploaded file to shared folder \\foobar\foo\fil\ENV1\ABMylocingZone\TIMS\FileTemplates\12345678_12345678_01ab1ab12abc-99f5-4a43-9127-01ab1ab12abc.xlsx | CopyToSharedFolder()
```

The `description` part explained :

```
.*      # greedily consumes characters 
(                           # matches a filename beginning with a number :
  \\(?<FooBar>[0-9]+)      # one "\", a number,
  _[^\\]+                     # one _, anything but a "\" once or more
  \.[a-zA-Z0-9]+              # a file extension
)
.*       # the rest of it
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately I couldn't use this within New Relic.

Comment: I did not realise you used grok inside New Relic : `%(?<message>[a-zA-Z]+%(?<hidden_message>%{NUMBER})[a-zA-Z]+)` might work (with `%` before the opening parenthesis). Can I let you try ? I'll edit my answer if this works :-)
source: https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/custom-grok-patterns-in-parsing-rules/143835

Comment: @Imsec, Appreciate your efforts on this.  My request for assistance came at a time and a project when I was utilizing New Relic and their logs.  I've moved on to another firm.  I'm hoping someone else can use what you've done on their projects.  Thanks again!

Comment: @ImTheOneNow No problem, if my answer seems correct to you then you may mark it as accepted so the issue appears as resolved.